# How to serialize nested many to many relation in django-rest-framework?

Tags: python, angularjs, json, django, django-rest-framework

Hi i have django model with following contents and i try to serialize it:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    recommended = models.ManyToManyField('self')
```

after serialization i get following Json:

```
"recommended": [
    2,
    3,
    1,
    38,
    39,
    40,
],
```

After this, i try to set it in template:

```
<div class="catalog-item" ng-repeat="recommended in product.recommended">
                    <div class="item-img">
                        <a href=""><img src="{{recommended.picture.external_img_url}}" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="item-title">{{ recommended.title }}</a>
                    <div class="item-price">
                        <div class="price-old">{{ recommended.oldprice }}</div>
                        <b>{{ recommended.price }}</b>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

My Product Serializer class:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    picture = ImageSerializer(read_only=True)
    vendor = VendorSerializer()

    class Meta:
          model = Product

          fields = (
                'name', 'external_url', 'category', 'description', 'price', 'old_price', 'discount', 'discount_percent',
                'popularity', 'order', 'click_count', 'redirect_count', 'visible', 'colors', 'sizes', 'currencies',
                'picture', 'country_of_origin', 'manufacturer_warranty', 'vendor','recommended','id')
```

And i get nothing in my page. Help me pls, i have no ideas how to fix it

Comment: There is not enough information to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer it myself, this moment is actually described in the documentation , just to our serializer class need to add depth settings
It's looks like this:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

picture = ImageSerializer(read_only=True)
vendor = VendorSerializer()

class Meta:
      model = Product

      fields = (
            'name', 'external_url', 'category', 'description', 'price', 'old_price', 'discount', 'discount_percent',
            'popularity', 'order', 'click_count', 'redirect_count', 'visible', 'colors', 'sizes', 'currencies',
            'picture', 'country_of_origin', 'manufacturer_warranty', 'vendor','recommended','id')

      depth = 2
```